# ZF2 - Service manager error: invalid factory registered

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I follwed the following tutorial to understand how Doctrine works: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

I now have a better understanding of Doctrine. However I am struggling to understand the entity manager and how to use it.

In the tutorial to get an instance of the entity manager, all you do is this:

```
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

That is loaded in the bootstrap and is available through out the code base.

So my question is, how is this instantiated in ZF2?

**EDIT: I have had some help on this via ZF Talk and the following was recommended to me. I am still however struggling to get it to work:**

My goal is to pull an array of users from my database and output them to my view using Doctrines pagination class.

In my Controller for the given action I have:

```
  public function usersAction() {
   $userFunctions = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Administration\Model\UserFunctionFactory');
    $userArray = $userFunctions->getUsers();
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('users' => $userArray));
    return $viewModel;
}
```

The users function Model is as such:

```
namespace Administration\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

class UserFunctions
{

protected $em;

function __constructor(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getUsers()
{
    $em = $this->em;

    $dql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql)
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults(100);

    $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

    $c = count($paginator);
    foreach ($paginator as $post) {
        $myArray[] = $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
    }
return $myArray;
}

}
```

The factory for the SM:

```
<?php
namespace Administration\UserFunctionFactory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Administration\Model\UserFunctions;

class UserFunctionsFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        return new UserFunctions($em);
    }
}
```

The module.config:

```
    'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Administration\Model\UserFunctionFactory' => 'Administration\Model\UserFunctionFactory')
),
```

I am getting the following error:

```
While attempting to create administrationmodeluserfunctionfactory(alias: Administration\Model\UserFunctionFactory) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.
```

Comment: You should check out the [`DoctrineModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule#doctrinemodule-for-zend-framework-2) when integrating Doctrine with ZF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what basically you should never do in a ZF2 controller

```
$userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
```

Instead you create a service (your UserFunctions) and get it in your controller using the service locator

```
namespace Administration\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface,
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

use Administration\Model\UserFunctions;

class UserFunctionsFactory 
    implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new UserFunctions($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
    }
}
```

So you user functions class constructor will be

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

// class declaration and props here

function __constructor(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
     $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

Then you register the service

```
// file services.config.php
namespace Administration;

return array(
    'factories' => array(
        'admin.service.contact' => new Service\UserFunctionsFactory()
    ),
);
```

Please note that you can do injection using **initializers** more than use class constructor. I used this method in the above example for simplicity.

This is an example of an initializer that inject DoctrineEntityManager

```
namespace My\Service\Initializer;

use Zend\ServiceManager\InitializerInterface,
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface,
    Zend\Debug\Debug;

    use My\Service\EntityManagerAwareInterface;

    class EntityManagerAwareInitializer 
        implements InitializerInterface
    {
        public function initialize($instance, ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
        {
            if($instance instanceof EntityManagerAwareInterface) {
                $instance->setEntityManager($serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager'));
            }
        }
    }
```

and the interface

```
namespace My\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

interface EntityManagerAwareInterface 
{
    /**
     * Set Doctrine 2 Entity Manager
     * 
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager);

    /**
     * Get Doctrine 2 Entity Manager
     */
    function getEntityManager();
}
```

and the registration of the initializer

```
'initializers' => array(
    'My\Service\Initializer\EntityManagerAwareInitializer' => new EntityManagerAwareInitializer()
),
```

Please note that I have separated configuration files because my module implements some interfaces that gives the possibility to do so, for example

```
namespace My;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ControllerProviderInterface,
    Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface,
    Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module 
    implements 
        AutoloaderProviderInterface,
        ControllerProviderInterface,
        ServiceProviderInterface,
        ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../../config/controllers.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../../config/services.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/../../src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

My Module.php is inside my src, so pay attention to paths.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Hi Sergio - thank you for this, it helped and for now I am going to use your suggestion since I just do not quite have the talent at this point in time to get more complex solutions working.

Comment: You welcome! 

I suggest you to look for the docs about the service locator because there are other service types that is better to know.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate issue (based on your code snippets, and the resulting error about the factory being invalid) is actually trivial.

Your module.config.php says the factory class is:

`Administration\Model\UserFunctionFactory`,

but the fully-qualified class name of the class defined in your factory's classfile is:

`Administration\UserFunctionFactory\UserFunctionFactory`

The namespace mismatch means the SM can't find your factory.  So, your first fix is to make sure your factory is indeed defined in a file like `Administration/src/Administration/Model/UserFunctionsFactory.php` (assuming your module is using PSR-0), and change the first line to read `namespace Administration/Model`

Comment: Thank you Tim - I did find the error which opened up a can of worms for a whole bunch of other errors :S